# I cant mount my newly created partition in gparted

Tags: mount, partitioning

The option to mount my new partition is grayed out and I need the partition mounted so i can use it to create a Linux Distro using LinuxFromScratch.

Comment: Could you please add a little more detail? What *exactly* did you do, what did you want to achieve and what happened instead? Did you encounter any warning or error messages? Please reproduce them in their entirety in your question. You can select, copy and paste terminal content and most dialogue messages in Ubuntu. (see [How do I ask a good question?](/help/how-to-ask))

Comment: I had the same problem with the mount option being greyed out. Solution is to use the disks utility. You can start it from the GUI menu or by typing `gnome-disks` in a terminal. There you can easily mount it.

Answer (score 6):

I'm not an expert, but I don't think you can mount a partition in GParted. You can only unmount one which is required before you can do anything with it. So, you're going to have to mount your partition manually. Here's the command that's used to do that:

```
$ sudo mount -t auto \
> -o rw \
> /dev/[BLOCK_DEVICE][PARTITION_NUMBER] [MOUNT_POINT] \
> -v
```

If your partition is `/dev/sdb1`, you mount it at the `mnt` directory like this:

```
$ sudo mount -t auto \
> -o rw \
> /dev/sdb1 /mnt \
> -v
```

Comment: There *is* a "mount" option in GParted's menu; however, it's greyed out unless the partition has a matching entry in `/etc/fstab`. In the absence of such an entry, this answer should work, and the text-mode `mount` command is the most generally-applicable solution. Many desktop environments and GUI file managers also have options to mount partitions, typically to subdirectories of `/media`, but details of how to use these features vary from one desktop environment or file manager to another.

Comment: what does "mount point" mean? what is "mnt" directory? does it matter?

Comment: Basically, a mount point is the directory that gives you access to whatever you have mounted there. "mnt" is just a directory in your root directory. It doesn't have to be "mnt". You can create your own directory and mount your drives there.

Comment: Yes, it's very confusing, but when you plug in a USB drive, it isn't Linux mounting it for you, but it's your file manager (Nautilus, Nemo, etc). If you don't want to just pull the drive and stick it back in (because you fear data loss), run `sync` (without parameters) in a terminal before doing that.