# Hard Drives Disapeered After Installing Ubuntu

Tags: storage

I switched from windows to ubuntu, and I downloaded it on my SSD but I have 2 extra 2TB hard drives that I use for file storage, however I don't see them on my file systems tab in ubuntu or near my computer tab in the files menu, but if I run the fdisk command they show up. Here is what it shows:

```
Disk /dev/sda: 111.8 GiB, 120034123776 bytes, 234441648 sectors
Units: sectors of 1 * 512 = 512 bytes
Sector size (logical/physical): 512 bytes / 512 bytes
I/O size (minimum/optimal): 512 bytes / 512 bytes
Disklabel type: gpt
Disk identifier: A574EF4F-E377-49DE-B460-E8A058323EB3

Device         Start       End   Sectors  Size Type
/dev/sda1       2048   1050623   1048576  512M EFI System
/dev/sda2    1050624 201019391 199968768 95.4G Linux filesystem
/dev/sda3  201019392 234440703  33421312   16G Linux swap


Disk /dev/sdb: 1.8 TiB, 2000398934016 bytes, 3907029168 sectors
Units: sectors of 1 * 512 = 512 bytes
Sector size (logical/physical): 512 bytes / 512 bytes
I/O size (minimum/optimal): 512 bytes / 512 bytes
Disklabel type: gpt
Disk identifier: 2E653A29-6C65-4A06-B56E-36BBCF7DDE8C

Device      Start        End    Sectors  Size Type
/dev/sdb1      34       2081       2048    1M Microsoft LDM metadata
/dev/sdb2    2082     262177     260096  127M Microsoft reserved
/dev/sdb3  262178 3907029134 3906766957  1.8T Microsoft LDM data


Disk /dev/sdc: 1.8 TiB, 2000398934016 bytes, 3907029168 sectors
Units: sectors of 1 * 512 = 512 bytes
Sector size (logical/physical): 512 bytes / 512 bytes
I/O size (minimum/optimal): 512 bytes / 512 bytes
Disklabel type: gpt
Disk identifier: F746C225-D7CE-40EC-814B-47FE9831C6DB

Device      Start        End    Sectors  Size Type
/dev/sdc1      34       2081       2048    1M Microsoft LDM metadata
/dev/sdc2    2082     262177     260096  127M Microsoft reserved
/dev/sdc3  262178 3907029134 3906766957  1.8T Microsoft LDM data
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can't access disk partitions unless they are mounted. So, you first need to mount them. Check out this post: [I cant mount my newly created partition in gparted](https://askubuntu.com/questions/900974/i-cant-mount-my-newly-created-partition-in-gparted/901002#901002)

To have your system automatically mount them at boot-time, you need to make configuration changes to the `/etc/fstab` file. Follow [this link](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/Fstab) to get more information on how to do that. Same can be achieved in [**Disks** app in Ubuntu](https://askubuntu.com/a/271527/665251)