# Ubuntu install on USB

Tags: system-installation, usb-installation

I want to install Ubuntu on a USB (full install) Its a 64 gb usb so I have plenty of space. In the live mode I try to install it but its stuck (I waited 8 hours) on creating ext4 file system for / after i saw this warning (clicked on continue):

> The attempt to mount a file system with type ext4 in SCSI1 (0,0,0), patition #3 (sdb) at / failed.
> You may resume partitioning from the partitioning menu.
> **go back**/**continue**

When I click on Go Back then the progress bar disappears.

Comment: I think you are trying to install the system on the same stick you are booting from. You need to use 2 sticks. 1 to boot from and the other 1 to install the system on.

Comment: I have 2, i use 2

Comment: Good. Did you try what unimatrix2 suggested, make the partitions before actual installing the system?

Comment: Yes im trying that

Comment: Ubuntu can be installed to the pendrive it was booted from, See: https://askubuntu.com/questions/855039/can-ubuntu-be-installed-to-the-pendrive-it-was-booted-from

Answer (score 0):

Try setting up your partitions before installing, and creating a new Partition Table on the process.

From your live session, open gparted, create a new partition table on your pendrive (if your machine(s) support UEFI Boot use GPT, else use MBR), format the space as ext4 (if you get errors during this process, you may have bad storage on your pendrive) and do the regular setup. Beware that pendrive installs are very slow and prone to errors.

Comment: Does not work. GParted can't mount ext4 partition. Saying that i don't have e2fsprogs but i checked and it said newest version. I can try to install but didn't try yet.

Comment: That's weird, can it at least create the partition table? If so, did you try manually mounting it after creating the partition? (https://askubuntu.com/questions/900974/i-cant-mount-my-newly-created-partition-in-gparted). Is it viable to you to try swapping the drives used? Also, at this point I would check the iso integrity (checksum) just to be sure. I never had a problem downloading ubuntu from official torrent, but every single "regular" download resulted in faulty installs. Try copying files to the drive, ejecting, put it back and test the files, this could still be a faulty drive.

Comment: sooo i also created a fat32 and swap partition and theyre ok, but the ext4 partition is now a unknown fs and before it could change to unknown but it throwed a error (forgot to copy) , i tried to mount it in nautilius.

Comment: ...before it could change to unknown *i tried to mount it* but it throwed a error.

Comment: Linux check USB stick or errors:

The procedure to check the physical health of a USB pen drive in Linux:

    Open the terminal application.
    Insert your USB stick or pen drive into Linux system.
    To test and detect bad sector in USB flash memory or pen drive, run: badblocks -w -s -o error.log /dev/sdX .
    To error check USB flash drive, you can use the f3write and f3read commands, which is an alternative to h2testw app from Windows operating systems. See also https://www.cyberciti.biz/faq/linux-check-the-physical-health-of-a-usb-stick-flash-drive/

Comment: @JoepieEs So i need to install the f3write and f3read packages?

Comment: Did you run 'badblocks -w -s -o error.log /dev/sdX' ( replacing the sdX with the name of your stick )? F3 is a simple tool that tests flash cards capacity and performance to see if they live up to claimed specifications. F3 stands for Fight Flash Fraud, or Fight Fake Flash. So these program are more designed to see if a low end usb flashdrive is relabeled for a much higher spec one ( to get more money ). So you don't really need to install these programs, unless you want to check this. Runnig the command should be sufficient to see if there are any bad sectors on the flash drive.

Comment: Hi, its still running:  pattern 0x55, 40% done, 3:30:00 elapsed (It's a 64 GB pendrive/usb)